# (javascript) how to do a reverse regex replace sentence start with tab?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to keep all sentences start with one Tab [key \t] and delete the rest

**input**

```
This is aciton
        Two tab
    One tabdialog
This is aciton
        Two tab
    Second tabdialog
```

**output**

```
One tabdialog

Second tabdialog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this simple regex for this:

```
^\t\S.*
```

Where we match `\t` (tab) after line start followed by a non-whitespace character which is followed by 0 or more of any characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ECxWOS/1)

**Code:**

```js
const str = `
This is aciton
        Two tab
    One tabdialog
This is aciton
        Two tab
    Second tabdialog
`;

var arr = str.match(/^\t\S.*/gm);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Hey this work better adding /S in the regex

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this as

```
^\t[\w ]+
```

[DEMO](https://regexr.com/64aff)

[image]

```js
const str = `
This is aciton
        Two tab
    One tabdialog
This is aciton
        Two tab
    Second tabdialog
`;

const regex = /^\t[\w ]+/gm;
const result = str
  .match(regex)
  .flatMap((s) => s.split(/\t/))
  .filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `match` we can try the following approach:

```js
var input = "This is aciton\n\t\tTwo tab\n\tOne tabdialog\nThis is aciton\n\t\tTwo tab\n\tSecond tabdialog";
console.log(input);

var matches = input.match(/(?:^|\n)\t([^\t]+?)(?:\r?\n|$)/g);
for (var i=0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
    matches[i] = matches[i].trim();
}
console.log(matches);
```